# How to make popup position relative to overall page instead of button that triggered it

Tags: html, jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to code a pop-up that triggers when an image is clicked, and it is essentially working but the popup is aligning itself to the image that triggered it. I need to align it to the center of the overall page, I have tried messing with the margins and setting all the div class to align="center" but none of that has helped. This is inside an Elementor widget, which I believe is basically just a CSS flexbox.

```
<div class="popup">
  <img src="image1.png">
</div>
<div class="showcompliant">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="img-showcompliant" align="center">
    <div align="right"><span>X</span></div>
      <div class="icon">
  </div>
  <div class="description">
 Lorem ipsum dolor amet sit. 
  </div>
  <div class="illustrationcomplaints"></div>
  <style>
   .illustrationcomplaints {
  background-image: url("image2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:600px;
height: 100px;
}   
  </style>
  <div align="center">
  <div class="dismiss-btn">
 
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>

<style>
 .popup{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center

}

.popup:hover {

    position: relative;
    top: -5px;  
}

.popup img{
    width: 390px;
    height: 140px;
    cursor: pointer
    z-index: 75;
}
.showcompliant{
    display: none;
    z-index: 101;
    align-self: center;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
}

.showcompliant .img-showcompliant{
    width:650px;
    height:350px;
    align-content: center;
    background: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
.img-showcompliant span{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.img-showcompliant img{

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}   

.description {
    padding:25px;
    color: #1a1a1a;
}

.overlay {
    align-content: center;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    
    $(".popup img").click(function () {
        var $src = $(this).attr("src");
        $(".showcompliant").fadeIn();
        $(".img-showcompliant img").attr("src", $src);
    });
    
    $("span, .overlay").click(function () {
        $(".showcompliant").fadeOut();
    });
    
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good day. Try to help you...
As I understand you need to use flexbox and use "flex-direction: column;"
Please see this pretty simple html + css how to use it.
Let me know if it helps you?

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.container{
  
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#ccc;
  flex-direction:column;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
 <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png">
</div>
```

Comment: I added a wrapper to the pop-up similar to your snippet, and it is still centering to the button instead of the page.

Comment: Neverminded sorry, I found the problem, one of the CSS properties had the position set to relative, as long as everything is set to absolute this works.

Comment: Good! Thank you..